# Assign return value from python method to a variable in bash script

Tags: python-2.7, shell

From a shell script, I am executing python program. I am trying to assign the return value from python to a variable in shell script and comparing this variable in if else condition. I don't know where I made a mistake either in code or some syntax. Please help me getting the correct output.

test.sh

```
#!bin/sh
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
password="Testing@2134testing"
password_check=$(python password.py $password)
if [ "$password_check" == "True" ];then
    echo "Correct"
else
    echo "Incorrect"
fi
```

password.py

```
import re, sys
password = sys.argv[1]
def passwordCheck():
       if re.match(r'(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).{14,}', password):
            return True;
       else:
            return False;
```

Even the password meets the requirement, it is always showing incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this:

```
password_check=$(python password.py $password)
```

You are assigning the *output* of the `password.py` program to the `password_check` variable.  The problem is that your `password.py` program doesn't produce any output: in fact, it never even runs the `passwordCheck` function, because your Python script never calls `passwordCheck`.  Do make things work the way you're trying to use the script, you would need to modify it to (a) actually call the `passwordCheck` method and (b) print output instead of `return`ing a value:

```
import re, sys
password = sys.argv[1]
def passwordCheck():
    if re.match(r'(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).{14,}', password):
        print 'okay'
        return True
    else:
        print 'fail'
        return False

passwordCheck()
```

And then check for that value in your shell script:

```
#!bin/sh

password="Testing@2134testing"
password_check=$(python password.py $password)
if [ "$password_check" == "okay" ];then
    echo "Correct"
else
    echo "Incorrect"
fi
```

Note that Python doesn't require a terminal `;` on lines, so instead
of:

```
return False;
```

You should write:

```
return False
```

Additionally, in this example we're using the *output* of the script
to determine success/failure.  A slightly more robust solution is to
use the *exit code* of the script instead.  You can probably find a
variety of examples of using this technique if you explore online a
bit.

Comment: Is `print` statement necessary?

Comment: I think it is mandatory since bash is reading from `stdout`. I tried using `return` instead `print` doesn't seem to cooperate though.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying any attention to the original question in my last comment. Yes, since we're calling this in a script that wants the output, we need to use `print` (because otherwise there is no output).